# JQuery Fancybox no longer working - Opens images on new screen, instead of same screen

Tags: jquery

I am using 'Fancy box' - A piece of JQuery that lets you click images to see them full size without leaving the current screen.

It was working fine when I used it a week ago, but after lots of coding changes on various pages, I now see it's not working, and when clicking an image it just opens on a new screen.

Is there something very obvious that I'm doing wrong from what you see here?

```
<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

    });
</script>
```

Link to show large image:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="1_b.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: Did you receive any error in the browser console?

Comment: Two possible reasons. Either, on of your scripts isn't loading or some other script is conflicting with jQuery. Make sure that you are loading jQuery and the fancybox scripts just fine.

Comment: I receive no errors. There must be something conflicting, but I honestly cannot see what.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the fancy box was not configured properly.

Check the console for errors.

However looks like `you are missing jQuery.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/source/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
```